# Creating a user-friendly list of timezones for user-preferences

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

Below is a snippet of the list of timezones returned from java (I've printed the timezone offset, timezone ID, and long name, using JodaTime).

```
(GMT-10:00) HST, Hawaii Standard Time     
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/Apia, -10:00
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/Fakaofo, Tokelau Time
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/Honolulu, Hawaii Standard Time
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/Johnston, Hawaii Standard Time
```

What is the difference between **HST**, **Pacific/Honolulu**, and **Pacific/Johnston**, for example? They all seem to use **Hawaii Standard Time**, why are there 3 entries in the database?

- My ultimate goal is to just create a list of timezones for user preferences in a web app.

If I use all of the timezones from the tzDatabase the list is long and appears to have effective duplicates (example above). I could just list unique long-form-names such as "Hawaii Standard Time", but then I need to decide how to map it to any one of the timezones that use that same long name.

What do other people do in this case? How do you create a nice user-friendly list of timezones and map them to their relevant java TimeZone?

Comment: please check out the Locales... they mite differ

Comment: Great comment, good idea, but I think there's only one Locale for the US right? And like 6 timezones in total (Hawii, Alaska, pacific, mountain, central, eastern).

Comment: hmmm nt sure whats the issue then... check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_time_zones something mite strike...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are making the assumption that "user-friendly" means to show them a small list. The fact is though that all of those time zones are used by someone, somewhere. They may look the same to you but they often have slightly different behaviour. I live in Saskatchewan and we have our own version of CST. The long name is only "Central Standard Time" but we don't use DST so for half of the year, we don't line up with real CST. There is even one small area of Saskatchewan which has a 15 min difference in the time. Even if they seem the same, they are different and I think you should allow the users to select from the whole list.

Trying to *intelligently* shorten the list might be comparable to not listing all possible currency codes when allowing a user to select a preferred currency. Yes, there may only be a handful of people who use certain ones. Sure, there may be some with the same conversion rates currently. In the end, let the user decide what they care about.

One solution for showing large lists or potentially *un-important* data with only a few items of real interest: Determine the commonly used ones first and then separate them to the top of the list. This can be seen on various websites for selecting Country, for example:

```
Canada
United States
------------------
Argentina
Australia
...
```

This strategy is also often used for my previous example of currency. It could look something like this for time-zones (If your main user base is in North America):

```
EST
CST
MST
PST
------------------
Hawaii
Saskatchewan
...
```

Remember though, this will require you to manually, pre-determine what the *common* time zones are.

I feel the best approach is to simply list **all** timezones, sorted by offset because *most* people will know where to find there zone based on offset. For instance, I always look first for "-6:00", not Saskatchewan. Hope this helps!

Comment: If you do decide to have many items in a `<select>` element, I recomend using the [Chosen JS framework](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) which improves the usability of large drop-downs.

Comment: CST (Central Standard Time) is always the same time, regardless of Daylight Saving Time. I think you meant to say that while typically Central Time alternates between Central Daylight Time and Central Standard Time, you stay in Central Standard Time all year long. CDT and CST are two separate time zones, and some places alternate time zones depending on the time of year.

Comment: To me, "user friendly list of timezones" would be a list that expresses Pacific/Galapagos as "Galapagos Islands" or America/Guayaquil as "Ecuador (continental territory)"... I'm afraid I'm going with @JesseWebb suggestion. Sigh...

Answer (score 6):

The [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) data contains a list of "important" time-zones and can probably be used to pick the ones to display. (I remember something else, but [this](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/zone_tzid.html) is the best I can find now)

Multiple time zone ids will exist for the same place if the data was different in the past, or if the place has been renamed (the alias feature in the time-zone data). Removing the backward file when compiling the time-zone data would remove most aliases.

Comment: I'm unable to locate this CLDR list of important time zones. Can anyone provide a direct link?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not the timezone uses daylight savings time is probably the most common difference.

Comment: Probably not only **if** it uses, but **when** does the summer/winter switch take place. (I have no idea if it applies to Hawaii / HST)

Comment: These appear to all use Hawaii standard time, but I think that they might have had different DST changes in the past, something the tzDatabase tracks. But I still wonder what strategy people use to construct a good list of timezones for a simple user preferences form that correspond to a rational set of java timezones for use in conversion.

Comment: @Grzegorz, some timezones actually *don't* switch to DST

Comment: agree, I just wanted to indicate that even if a timezone switches to DST, you can never be sure when it happens. No worries.